# Ubuntu tunnel or gateway

Tags: ubuntu, routes, gateway

I have three different servers based on [Ubuntu 12.04](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Ubuntu_releases#Ubuntu_12.04_LTS_.28Precise_Pangolin.29) (Precise Pangolin). The main idea to route specific traffic through one server.

```
Server A - 144.50.1.25;
Server B - 144.55.23.21;
Server C - 144.10.12.34;
```

How do I create a tunnel which routes all traffic from Server A to Server C through Server B?

```
A -> B -> C
```

I've tried to set up route, but it doesn't help me:

On Server A:

```
#route add -host 144.10.12.34 gw 144.55.23.21 eth0
```

> SIOCADDRT: Network is unreachable

Comment: Not a programming question.

Comment: Try asking on [AskUbuntu](http://askubuntu.com) which is a StackExchange site just for Ubuntu questions like this one.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you have to set up:

- Network mask
- "dev" parameter

> $ route add -host 144.10.12.34**/24** gw 144.55.23.21 **dev** eth0

Also, "SIOCADDRT: Network is unreachable" is typical when you use a host address other than a ***network*** address! So change to a correct address:

> $ route add -host 144.10.12**.0**/24 gw 144.55.23.21 dev eth0